# IFR training in the free route airspace

Tags: flight-training, instrument-flight-rules, easa-regulations

The free route airspace is spreading in Central Europe, consuming routes and decomissioning VORs. There are no routes left in the high airspace, and some of the FIRs keep a few low (up to FL95) RNAV routes while others don't have any at all. Some ground-based navaids were decommissioned too. That means any and all IFR flight requires GNSS-based RNAV capability.

Is the training syllabus for instrument license changed accordingly to assume the licensee will always fly an RNAV-capable aircraft as that's required everywhere in their home country, or is there some way to train VOR, DME and NDB-based non-RNAV procedures provided?

Comment: VOR, DME, NDB etc. are still used for approaches in many places, just not so much enroute

Comment: @expeditedescent I first thought that all the VORs were decomissioned, because skyvector started showing them grayed out and without the compass rose. But at least in Czechia the AIP still lists all the VORs as active and available for navigation, including the en-route ones, and the on-airport ones are used for VOR+DME approaches, though all STARs are RNAV.

Comment: Many VORs are decommissioned, but some VORs and DMEs need to stay to provide basic RNAV coverage